# Deploy django aws

Tags: python, django, aplicación-web, aws, backend

Soy nuevo en el tema del deploy django(python)

Estos son los comandos ejecutados para el mismo

- Paso 1:

  ```
    pip install awsebcli --upgrade
  ```
- Paso 2:

  ```
    aws configure
        AWS Access Key ID : *******
        AWS Secret Access Key : *******
        region name : us-west-2
        output format : json
  ```
- Paso 3:

  ```
    eb init
        Select a default region     us-west-2 : US West (Oregon)
        Select an application to use     name application
  ```
- Paso 4:

  ```
    eb status  (para confirmar los datos de configurados del entorno)
    eb deploy  (para hacer un despliegue de la version para que el despliegue
                tome los cambios deben estar commiteados)
  ```

En el proyecto de Django:

- Cree una carpeta `.ebextensions` y dentro cree un archivo `django.config` con el siguiente codigo:

  ```
    options_settings:
      aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
         WSGIPath:backend_log/wsgi.py
  ```

La única vía  de poner en marcha el servidor es conectado  por ssh y luego ejecutar el comando python manage.py runserver(esto no debe ser). Les agradeceré si me ayudan en esta problemática

Comment: No veo que tengas ningún problema al respecto... o al menos no has comentado ninguno

Comment: El problema es que tengo que entrar vía ssh al servidor y ejecutar el comando python manage.py runserver.Cuando se cierra la conexión ssh,deja de dar servicio.He visto que le funciona a los desarrolladores sin tener que hacer lo antes expuesto o sea de forma automática

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes evitar al trabajar en AWS es alojar credenciales en las instancias EC2. Cualquier fallo de configuración puede permitir a un tercero hacerse con esas credenciales y de ahí a que las use para crear decenas de máquinas que minen bitcoins a costa del dinero de tu bolsillo hay un paso.

Para dotar a las instancias EC2 de privilegios de acceso a los diferentes servicios de AWS debes usar roles IAM. Vas al servicio IAM y creas un rol con los privilegios mínimos que precise la instancia EC2 para funcionar. Después vas al servicio EC2, seleccionas la instancia y le asocias el rol que acabas de crear... no hay usuarios ni contraseñas de por medio.

En cuanto a lo de arrancar el servidor, mi sugerencia es que en vez de montar el servicio directamente en la instancia, te crees un contenedor docker con todo lo que necesitas.

Las imágenes docker se pueden almacenar en el servicio ECR de AWS, lo que te permite aislar el servicio de la instancia (si terminas la instancia por error podrás replicar el servicio en otra máquina simplemente descargando la imagen del contenedor en otra instancia ) para, por ejemplo, replicar el servicio facilmente en varias máquinas.

La web de Docker tiene un [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) sobre cómo abarcar esta tarea.